# update the row in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have `Ipr_forms` table in my Db i want to update the row but the following code give me `job_id` of that table.which is not my requirement.....i want table id to update the existing table

**My controller code**

```
          $id =$this->request->data['IprForm']['id'];                                                                           
          $ipr_forms['job_id'] =  $this->request->data['IprForm']['job_id'];
          $ipr_forms['IprForm'] =  $this->request->data['IprForm'];           
          $this->IprForm->id = $id;
        //debug($id); 
          $ipr_forms_save = $this->IprForm->save($ipr_forms);
```

If i debug the id ,`$id` variable hold the job_id ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i can give you an example to edit any record in cakephp with multiple fields

just take look in function and you may have good idea

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        $this->Post->id = $id;
        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been updated.'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your post.'));
        }
    }

    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $post;
    }
}
```

or you can also refer detail [cakephp.org link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html) with title of editing posts